# Drawing line between the center points of buttons, can't find centers

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

In a constraint layout I have a column of 6 buttons. they are chained together and the top button is  constrained to the action bar and the bottom button is constrained to a guide just above the nav bar. To the left of the column I have another button.  I've drawn lines between the two sets of buttons - see pic.

[image]

The lines are sourced from a custom view and have been added to my xml. Here's some of the code inside my custom view that draws the lines.

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.GradientStart);
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

    canvas.drawLine(pointA.x, pointA.y, pointB.x, pointB.y, paint);    }
public void setPointA(PointF point){
        pointA=point;}
public void setPointB(PointF point){
    pointB=point;}
```

My problem is I can't seem to get the beginning and end points in the center of each button.  Either the buttons have shifted up or the lines have shifted down.

Here is my xml for the buttons.  I've only added the top and bottom and a few of the middle buttons.  All the middle buttons have the same xml

```
<com.example.android.cop1803.LayoutCustom xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/mylayoutcustom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
tools:context="com.example.android.cop1803.MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="73dp">
<!---->
<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/MainCOPbtn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/max"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/max" 
<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton>

    android:id="@+id/x21"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/x22"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/maxsmall"/>

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x22"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/x23"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x21"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall"/>

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x23"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/x24"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x22"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall"/>

<com.example.android.cop1803.MyViewbutton
    android:id="@+id/x27"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/copbutton"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x26"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall"/>
```

Here is the code where I find the centerpoints

```
 public void drawLines(List<LineView> mlinesToDraw) {
            int[] viewALocationInWindow = new int[2];
            int[] viewBLocationInWindow = new int[2];

            vBtn1.getLocationInWindow(viewALocationInWindow);
            vBtn2.getLocationInWindow(viewBLocationInWindow);

            int[] viewALocationOnScreen = new int[2];
            int[] viewBLocationOnScreen = new int[2];

            vBtn1.getLocationOnScreen(viewALocationOnScreen);
            vBtn2.getLocationOnScreen(viewBLocationOnScreen);

            float Ax = vBtn1.getX();
            float Ay = vBtn1.getY();
            float Bx = vBtn2.getX();;
            float By = vBtn2.getY();

            final int lineStartX = ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) vBtn1.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin + (vBtn1.getMeasuredWidth() / 2)+vBtn1.getLeft();
            final int lineStartY = ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) vBtn1.getLayoutParams()).topMargin + (vBtn1.getMeasuredHeight() / 2)+vBtn1.getTop();
            final int lineEndX = ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) vBtn2.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin + (vBtn2.getMeasuredWidth() / 2)+vBtn2.getLeft();
            final int lineEndY = ((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) vBtn2.getLayoutParams()).topMargin + (vBtn2.getMeasuredHeight() / 2)+vBtn2.getTop();

        pointA=new PointF(lineStartX,  lineStartY);
        pointB=new PointF(lineEndX,lineEndY);
        mLine.get(i).setPointA(pointA);
        mLine.get(i).setPointB(pointB);
    } }
```

I've attached a 'getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener' to my main layout so the buttons are already rendered before I draw the lines.

Any help you can offer in finding the culprit is much appreciated.

Comment: @Cheticamp's answer looks pretty good, but if you continue to have trouble, you might want to take a look at [ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear which set of coordinates you are using. From appearances, it looks like the x-values are correct but the y-values are off. (Are you computing screen coordinates and using them to draw? That would give you correct `x` values but incorrect `y` values.) Check to make sure that your coordinates to `drawLine()` are being set correctly: computations for `x` going to the `x` coordinate and the same for `y`.

It is also not clear what is happening in `LayoutCustom`, so something could be going on there. Any translations of the coordinates could be throwing you off.

Here is quick example that may help you based upon your layout. I use `View.setForeground()` (API 23+) to write to a canvas but the concept remains the same.

[image]

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/mylayoutcustom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/MainCOPbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/max"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.14"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/max" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/x21"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/x22"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="@dimen/maxsmall"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/x22"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/x23"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x21"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/x23"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/x24"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x22"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/x24"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/x23"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="@dimen/maxsmall" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="16dp" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="382dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    private ConstraintLayout mLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mLayout = findViewById(R.id.mylayoutcustom);
        findViewById(R.id.mylayoutcustom).getViewTreeObserver()
            .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Button btns[] = new Button[]{
            findViewById(R.id.MainCOPbtn),
            findViewById(R.id.x21),
            findViewById(R.id.x22),
            findViewById(R.id.x23),
            findViewById(R.id.x24)};
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        mLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mLayout.getWidth(), mLayout.getHeight(),
                                         Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        drawCircle(canvas, btns[0], paint);
        for (int i = 1; i < btns.length; i++) {
            drawLine(canvas, btns[0], btns[i], paint);
        }
        BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
        mLayout.setForeground(d);
    }

    private void drawLine(Canvas canvas, View fromView, View toView, Paint paint) {
        Point from = getCenter(fromView);
        Point to = getCenter(toView);
        canvas.drawCircle(to.x, to.y, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y, paint);
    }

    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas, View view, Paint paint) {
        Point center = getCenter(view);
        canvas.drawCircle(center.x, center.y, 20, paint);
    }

    Point getCenter(View view) {
        Point pt = new Point();
        pt.x = (int) (view.getX() + view.getWidth() / 2);
        pt.y = (int) (view.getY() + view.getHeight() / 2);
        return pt;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your answer, though I finally found what mine was missing.  The issue was with the y axis.  The gap is was creating was due to the status bar height. Not sure why but for some reason it was not being considered in the Y coordinates.

Comment: @TeleJim How are you computing the "y" value? I suggest that you figure out what is wrong there.

Comment: via the following:
    final int lineStartY = ((((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
    vBtn1.getLayoutParams())
                        .topMargin+((ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) 
    vBtn1.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin
                         + vBtn1.getHeight()
                         -statusBarHeight) / 2)
                        +(int) Ay;
Same for the second y coordinate.